# Showing error Instance method 'appendInterpolation(_:formatter:)' requires that '[Int]' inherit from 'NSObject'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

This is my proper model for the variables and values that is to be stored in it from the api.

```
struct Items : Hashable,Codable {

    var id,origin_station_code,destination_station_code : Int
    var station_path : [Int]
    var date,state,city,map_url : String
}
```

This is the `View`:

```
struct SheetView: View {
    
    var items : Items
    
    @EnvironmentObject  var viewModel: ViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var personvm : PersonViewModel
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack(spacing:30)
        {
            URLImage(urlstring: items.map_url)
            
            
            
            VStack(spacing:20)
            {
                HStack
                {
                    VStack
                    {
                    Text("Ride ID").font(.subheadline)
                    Text("\(items.id)").fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack
                    {
                        Text("Origin Station").font(.subheadline)
                        Text("\(items.origin_station_code)").fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                }//First row
                
                Divider()
                
                HStack
                {
                    VStack
                    {
                        Text("Date").font(.subheadline)
                        Text(items.date).fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack
                    {
                        Text("Distance").font(.subheadline)
                        Text("100Km").fontWeight(.bold)
                        
                         }
                }//Second row
                
                Divider()
                
                HStack
                {
                    VStack
                    {
                        Text("State").font(.subheadline)
                        Text(items.state).fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack
                    {
                        Text("Distance").font(.subheadline)
                        Text(items.city)
                    }
                }//third row
                
                Divider()
                
                VStack{
                    Text("Station Path").font(.subheadline)
                    Text("\(items.station_path)") //The error occurs here and I am unable to print the array fetched from the api call

                }
                
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: `station_path` is an array (multiple values). What do you want to display?

Comment: If you want to use an array of `Int` (`[Int]) in a SwiftUI `Text` view. You need to convert it to a string somehow. Maybe a comma-separated string of those values. Try this: `Text(items.station_path.map(String.init).joined(separator: ", "))`